# How to make proper use of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm developing a helpdesk-like system, and I want to employ foreign keys, to make sure the DB structure is decent, but I don't know if I should use them at all, and how to employ them properly.

Are there any good tutorials on how (and when) to use Foreign keys ?

**edit** The part where I'm the most confused at is the ON DELETE .. ON UPDATE .. part, let's say I have the following tables

```
table 'users'
id int PK auto_increment
department_id int FK (departments.department_id) NULL
name varchar

table 'departments'
id int PK auto_increment
name
```

users.department_id is a foreign key from departments.department_id, how does the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE functions work here when i want to delete the department or the user?

Comment: You could do worse than read the myriad of [questions on foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreign+keys) on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need foreign keys if you are splitting your database into tables and you are working with a DBMS (e.g. MySQL, Oracle and others). I assume from your tags you are using MySQL.

If you don't use foreign keys your database will become hard to manage and maintain. The process of normalisation ensures data consistency, which uses foreign keys.

See [here for foreign keys.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) See here for [why foreign keys are important in a relational database here.](http://www.mahipalreddy.com/dbdesign/dbqa.htm)

Although denormalization is often used when efficiency is the main factor in the design. If this is the case you may want to move away from what I have told you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 although I don't agree that you *need* foreign keys just because you have tables, they certainly help in most situations.

Comment: For so far that's quite clear, how about the ON DELETE .. ON UPDATE .. part? (edited question)

Comment: Was going to post but noticed I couldn't have said it much better than Kerrek below.

Comment: "The process of normalisation ensures data consistency": actually, it eliminates some but not all update anomalies. "The process of normalisation ... uses foreign keys": you are confusing design with implementation. Normalisation can be a mere academic exercise without involving a DBMS at all.

Comment: That second link about 'why foreign keys are important' is pretty poorly written. It'd be nice if you could give a better description here.

Answer (score 5):

`ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` refer to how changes you make in the key table propagate to the dependent table. UPDATE means that the key values get changed in the dependent table to maintain the relation, and DELETE means that dependent records get deleted to maintain the integrity.

Example: Say you have

```
 Users: Name =  Bob, Department = 1
 Users: Name =  Jim, Department = 1
 Users: Name =  Roy, Department = 2
```

and

```
 Departments: id = 1, Name = Sales
 Departments: id = 2, Name = Bales
```

Now if you change the deparments table to modify the first record to read `id = 5, Name = Sales`, then with "UPDATE" you would also change the first two records to read `Department = 5` -- and without "UPDATE" you wouldn't be allowed to make the change!

Similarly, if you deleted Department 2, then with "DELETE" you would also delete the record for Roy! And without "DELETE" you wouldn't be allowed to remove the department without first removing Roy.